# How to automatically `git commit amend` to *append* to last commit message?

Tags: git

Trying to **edit** last commit message by appending a string in the end of the previous message.

Trying to do this from a CI server, so I'm looking for an automatic solution that doesn't require any interactive human intervention

Comment: how CI server will know that a wrong msg has been commited and a new message needs to be given, without manual intervention?

Comment: I'm using an external library with a certain flag that only commits a message and doesn't push it intentionally.
I need to append a string to it for important integration with the CI server that is triggered based on certain commit messages parameters.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to amend the current commit and change the commit message without opening an editor, you can use the `-m` flag to supply a message.  For example:

```
git commit --amend -m"This is the commit message."
```

Will amend the current HEAD, using the message given as the new message:

```
% git log
commit adecdcf09517fc4b709fc95ad4a83621a3381a45
Author: Edward Thomson <ethomson@edwardthomson.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 17 12:29:10 2017 +0000

    This is the commit message.
```

If you want to *append* the message, you'll need to fetch the previous one:

```
OLD_MSG=$(git log --format=%B -n1)
```

And then you can use that to set the new message, using multiple `-m`'s to set multiple lines:

```
git commit --amend -m"$OLD_MSG" -m"This is appended."
```

Which will append the given message to the original:

```
% git log
commit 5888ef05e73787f1f1d06e8f0f943199a76b70fd
Author: Edward Thomson <ethomson@edwardthomson.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 17 12:29:10 2017 +0000

    This is the commit message.

    This is appended.
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you

Comment: how would you go about aliasing this? (appending to last commit message)

Comment: any ideas for not adding the newlines?

Comment: @jayqui I don't know which newlines you're talking about precisely.  If you want to just remove all newlines from the old message, then you can use any command line tool.  `xargs` wasn't made to do this, but can.  For example: `OLD_MSG=$(git log --format=%B -n1 | xargs)`

Answer (score 7):

One way is to use the [`GIT_EDITOR`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var#git-var-GITEDITOR) environment variable and amend the commit:

```
GIT_EDITOR="echo 'appended line' >>" git commit --amend
```

where `appended line` is the content you want to insert.

This variable will set the editor to be used for this commit operation. Basically Git will execute whatever that variable is set to, passing a file name containing the commit message, i.e. `$GIT_EDITOR <file>` or, in this case, `echo 'appended line' >> <file>`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the one line that I use all the time to amend the last commit

```
git commit --amend -C head
```

the -C means "Take an existing commit object, and reuse the log message and the authorship information (including the timestamp) when creating the commit."

If you want to make other changes use `-c` instead

the -c means "Like -C, but with -c the editor is invoked, so that the user can further edit the commit message."

Comment: For interactive usage this is superior to the accepted answer (but the question was about automation). Just replace `head` with `HEAD`

Comment: `HEAD` may be necessary for some systems, but on macOS, `head` works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Combine `git log` with `git commit --amend`:

```
APPEND_MESSAGE="foo bar baz"
PREVIOUS_MESSAGE="$(git log --format=%B -n 1)"
git commit --amend -m "$PREVIOUS_MESSAGE" -m "$APPEND_MESSAGE"
```

Answer (score 1):

A great way to achieve this in one line would be

```
git commit --amend -m "$(git log --format=%B -n1)" -m "This is appended message"
```

Where the last path("This is appended message") is the additional message.